# How to combine every 100 files together in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a huge number of small text files in a directory. I wanted to combine every 100 files into a large file. Could anyone help me with a Linux Shell script to do this?

Comment: Help: yes. Write: no. [With which part did you get stuck when you tried for yourself](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? Grouping 100 files? Concatenating files? Writing the script?

Answer (score 2):

The following sketch will do it:

```
files=( * )                                 # list of files
idx=0                                       # start index of actual package
len=100                                     # files per package
pcount=0                                    # package counter

while [ $idx -le ${#files[@]} ] ; do
  cat "${files[@]:idx:len}" > pack${pcount}   # process subarray
  ((idx+=len))                              # start of next package
  ((pcount++))                              # number of next package 
done
```

The result are files named 'pack0', 'pack1', ...

Comment: Just use `files=(*)` -- that will preserve filenames with whitespace. Using `ls` like that will break filenames with whitespace into separate words.

Comment: Thanks, that's right. In addition the cat command needs quotes to handle filenames with whitespaces.

Comment: It works great.. thanks a lot. I just need to change as "files = (thefolder/*)" and put the results in another folder.

Answer (score 0):

appending the output to new.txt

```
cat *.txt >> new.txt
```

overwriting new.txt

```
cat *.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: I would assume the OP would expect to see the number `100` somewhere in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

If the files can be (re)moved, then it's fairly simple:

```
find text_files_dir/ -name '*.txt' | \
head -n 100 | \
while read f; do cat "$f" >> big_file && rm "$f"; done
```

or

```
find text_files_dir/ -name '*.txt' | \
head -n 100 | \
while read f; do cat "$f" >> big_file && mv "$f" some_place_else/; done
```

You could put this in a loop until there are no more text files left.